# There is $g(z)$ such that $g^n(z)=f(z)$ iff the order of the zeros of $f(z)$ are divisible by $n$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function and $n$ be a positive integer. Show that there is an entire function $g(z)$ such that $g^n(z)=f(z)$ iff the order of the zeros of $f(z)$ are divisible by $n$.

I proved the necessary condition: Let $z_0$ be a zero of $f(z)$ of order $m$. Then we can represent uniquely $f(z)=(z-z_0)^m f_1(z)$, where $f_1$ is an entire function sich that $f_1(z_0) \neq 0$. Since $g^n=f$, $z_0$ is a zero of $g^n$, ant then it's also a zero of $g$. Let $k$ be the order of the zero $z_0$ of $g$. So, there's a unique representation $g(z)=(z-z_0)^kg_1(z)$, where $g_1$ is an entire function sich that $g_1(z_0) \neq 0$. Then, $f(z)=g^n(z)=(z-z_0)^{kn}g_1^n(z)$. By uniqueness of this representation of $f$, $kn=m$ and $m$ is divisible by $n$.

Is this correct?

I don't know how to prove the sufficient condition.

Comment: easiest way imho is to show that an $n$th root exists locally in a small enough neighborhood of any $z \in \mathbb C$ - where $f(z) \ne 0$ it is immediate by taking  a holomorphic logarithm near $z$, where $f(z)=0$ use the hypothesis; then using that $\mathbb C$ is simply connected patch the $n$th roots together - for example doing analytic continuation on curves from a fixed point like $0$

Answer (score 0):

For  the converse part let $R>0$ and  the distinct zeros of $f$ in $D(0,R)$ be $z_1,z_2,...,z_k$ and let their orders be $n_1,n_2,...,n_k$ . Let $h(z)=\frac {f(z)} {(z-z_1)^{n_1}(z-z_2)^{n_2}....(z-z_k)^{n_k}}$. Then $h$ is analytic and  has no zeros in $D(0,R)$ (which is simply connected). This implies that  $h(z)=e^{\phi(z)}$ for some analytic function $\phi$ in this ball. Now let $g_R(z)=c(z-z_1)^{n_1/n}(z-z_2)^{n_2/n}...(z-z_k)^{n_k/n} e^{\phi (z) /n}$ where $c$ is a root of unity. Then $g_R^{n}=f$. Choose $c$ so that $g_R(0)$ is a  particular $n-th$ root of $f(0)$ assuming that $f(0) \neq 0$. (The case $f(0)=0$ is handled in an obvious way from the case $f(0) \neq 0$ and I will leave that to you).   Can you see $g_{n}$ coincides with $g_{n-1}$ on $B(0, n-1)$? Once you see that it follows that $g_n$'s together give an entire function $g$ with $g^{n}=f$

Comment: I don't see how $g_R(z)$ depends on $R$

Comment: @Twink $g_R$ depends on $R$ because the roots $z_j$ depend on $R$.

Comment: But then when you changed to $g_n$ the number of roots change? By "all the $g_n$'s together" you mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n$ or just $g_n$?

Comment: @Twink For each $n$ there exists an analytic function $g_n$ with $g_n(z)^{n}=f(z)$ for $|z|<n$. We have to make sure that these are consistent: $g_2(z)=g_1(z)$ when $|z| <1$ etc. Once you check this you can define one fuc tion $g$ as folows: for any $z$ choose $n >|z|$ and define $g(z)$ as $g_n(z)$.

Comment: I see. Can $c$ be any $n$-th root of $f(0)$ or does it have to be a special one?

Comment: @Twink You just want to make sure that $g_n(0)$ does no depend on $n$.  $c$ can be any $n-th$ root of $f(0)$.